# Asp.net http client json response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, http-get

Asp.net c#.
This is my json string that i am getting from external web address, i want to store it in a list and then display it using gridview.
it is giving an error i-e.

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AMS_WEB_Form.Employee]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'employees', line 1, position 13.

plz help,

**class that i am using,..**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    public string employee_name { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

**This is what i am doing....and calling this task in PageLoads event of view.**

```
async Task RunAsyncGetDataFromSource()
{
  using( var client = new HttpClient() )
  {               
     //HTTP get
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.88.598:6598/employees");
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
     {
       var jsonString =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonString);

       GridExternalUsersData.DataSource = data;
       GridExternalUsersData.DataBind();

       Response.Write("<script>alert('Data loaded successfully');</script>");
    }
  }           
}
```

**My JSON Output from WebAPI is in this format.**

"{\"employees\":[{\"employee_id\":1,\"employee_name\":\"Dalton Schimmel\"},{\"employee_id\":2,\"employee_name\":\"Caitlyn O'Kon\"},{\"employee_id\":3,\"employee_name\":\"Timmothy Bartell\"},{\"employee_id\":4,\"employee_name\":\"Mauricio Lind\"},{\"employee_id\":5,\"employee_name\":\"Mr. Imani Pfannerstill\"},{\"employee_id\":6,\"employee_name\":\"Mrs. Reagan Wehner\"},{\"employee_id\":7,\"employee_name\":\"Citlalli McCullough II\"},{\"employee_id\":8,\"employee_name\":\"Mrs. Fabian Leffler\"},{\"employee_id\":9,\"employee_name\":\"Blanca Langosh\"},{\"employee_id\":10,\"employee_name\":\"Kennith Watsica\"},{\"employee_id\":11,\"employee_name\":\"Fermin Leannon\"},{\"employee_id\":12,\"employee_name\":\"Estelle Windler\"},{\"employee_id\":13,\"employee_name\":\"Kurt Skiles\"},{\"employee_id\":14,\"employee_name\":\"Sienna Medhurst\"},{\"employee_id\":15,\"employee_name\":\"Orlando Bednar DVM\"},{\"employee_id\":16,\"employee_name\":\"Harley Leffler\"},{\"employee_id\":17,\"employee_name\":\"Nathaniel Crooks\"},{\"employee_id\":18,\"employee_name\":\"Hortense Jerde IV\"},{\"employee_id\":19,\"employee_name\":\"Coty Mills\"},{\"employee_id\":20,\"employee_name\":\"Savannah Grimes\"},{\"employee_id\":21,\"employee_name\":\"Ms. Darrick Moore\"},{\"employee_id\":22,\"employee_name\":\"Meta Hermann MD\"},{\"employee_id\":23,\"employee_name\":\"Mr. Ellsworth Sauer\"},{\"employee_id\":24,\"employee_name\":\"Salvatore Marks\"},{\"employee_id\":25,\"employee_name\":\"Rory Bahringer I\"},{\"employee_id\":26,\"employee_name\":\"Rory Robel Sr.\"},{\"employee_id\":27,\"employee_name\":\"Katheryn Erdman\"},{\"employee_id\":28,\"employee_name\":\"Lexie Deckow Jr.\"},{\"employee_id\":29,\"employee_name\":\"Erling Jenkins\"},{\"employee_id\":30,\"employee_name\":\"Chris Gusikowski\"},{\"employee_id\":31,\"employee_name\":\"Kelli Mraz\"},{\"employee_id\":32,\"employee_name\":\"Gregg Hartmann\"},{\"employee_id\":33,\"employee_name\":\"Darrel Olson\"},{\"employee_id\":34,\"employee_name\":\"Roxane Nicolas\"},{\"employee_id\":35,\"employee_name\":\"Julian Hintz\"},{\"employee_id\":36,\"employee_name\":\"Elian White\"},{\"employee_id\":37,\"employee_name\":\"Annabel Nader\"},{\"employee_id\":38,\"employee_name\":\"Brycen Vandervort V\"},{\"employee_id\":39,\"employee_name\":\"Ms. Gerald Roob\"},{\"employee_id\":40,\"employee_name\":\"Dr. Lesley Feil\"},{\"employee_id\":41,\"employee_name\":\"Owen Schmidt\"},{\"employee_id\":42,\"employee_name\":\"Kayden Effertz\"},{\"employee_id\":43,\"employee_name\":\"Muhammad Funk\"},{\"employee_id\":44,\"employee_name\":\"Justyn Klein\"},{\"employee_id\":45,\"employee_name\":\"Ms. Jennie Pfannerstill\"},{\"employee_id\":46,\"employee_name\":\"Ms. Celestine Konopelski\"},{\"employee_id\":47,\"employee_name\":\"Kayden Jones\"},{\"employee_id\":48,\"employee_name\":\"Dr. Anabelle Emmerich\"},{\"employee_id\":49,\"employee_name\":\"Mrs. Isabell Kemmer\"},{\"employee_id\":50,\"employee_name\":\"Jovani Kiehn\"},{\"employee_id\":51,\"employee_name\":\"Otis Schiller\"},{\"employee_id\":52,\"employee_name\":\"Mrs. Aron Daniel\"},{\"employee_id\":53,\"employee_name\":\"Lurline Mayer\"},{\"employee_id\":54,\"employee_name\":\"Tiana Wisozk\"},{\"employee_id\":55,\"employee_name\":\"Laila Predovic\"},{\"employee_id\":56,\"employee_name\":\"Moises Carter\"},{\"employee_id\":57,\"employee_name\":\"Lizzie Yost\"},{\"employee_id\":58,\"employee_name\":\"Zoe Kirlin\"},{\"employee_id\":59,\"employee_name\":\"Kirk Romaguera\"},{\"employee_id\":60,\"employee_name\":\"Travis Orn\"},{\"employee_id\":61,\"employee_name\":\"Dr. Okey Mertz\"},{\"employee_id\":62,\"employee_name\":\"Kristoffer Gerhold\"},{\"employee_id\":63,\"employee_name\":\"Unique Beier\"},{\"employee_id\":64,\"employee_name\":\"Mrs. Halle Runolfsson\"},{\"employee_id\":65,\"employee_name\":\"Ariane Kris\"},{\"employee_id\":66,\"employee_name\":\"Irma Witting III\"},{\"employee_id\":67,\"employee_name\":\"Rupert Streich PhD\"},{\"employee_id\":68,\"employee_name\":\"Dahlia Kemmer Sr.\"},{\"employee_id\":69,\"employee_name\":\"Ms. George Thompson\"},{\"employee_id\":70,\"employee_name\":\"Emie Green IV\"},{\"employee_id\":71,\"employee_name\":\"Miss Ibrahim Botsford\"},{\"employee_id\":72,\"employee_name\":\"Felton Waters IV\"},{\"employee_id\":73,\"employee_name\":\"Letitia Thiel\"},{\"employee_id\":74,\"employee_name\":\"Marquis Corwin\"},{\"employee_id\":75,\"employee_name\":\"Destini Rogahn V\"},{\"employee_id\":76,\"employee_name\":\"Carleton Steuber\"},{\"employee_id\":77,\"employee_name\":\"Amiya Von PhD\"},{\"employee_id\":78,\"employee_name\":\"Adele Kunde\"},{\"employee_id\":79,\"employee_name\":\"Miss Elijah Glover\"},{\"employee_id\":80,\"employee_name\":\"Joelle Thiel\"},{\"employee_id\":81,\"employee_name\":\"Eino Bogan\"},{\"employee_id\":82,\"employee_name\":\"Ms. Jake Kerluke\"},{\"employee_id\":83,\"employee_name\":\"Ethyl Waters\"},{\"employee_id\":84,\"employee_name\":\"Vanessa Lindgren\"},{\"employee_id\":85,\"employee_name\":\"Valentin Cummerata\"},{\"employee_id\":86,\"employee_name\":\"Dr. Halle Fadel\"},{\"employee_id\":87,\"employee_name\":\"Savanah King\"},{\"employee_id\":88,\"employee_name\":\"Christop Effertz\"},{\"employee_id\":89,\"employee_name\":\"Cristopher Jacobs\"},{\"employee_id\":90,\"employee_name\":\"Prudence Cruickshank II\"},{\"employee_id\":91,\"employee_name\":\"Karlee Herman\"},{\"employee_id\":92,\"employee_name\":\"Rosamond Rau\"},{\"employee_id\":93,\"employee_name\":\"Marina Fritsch\"},{\"employee_id\":94,\"employee_name\":\"Stefanie Johns\"},{\"employee_id\":95,\"employee_name\":\"Tevin Murazik\"},{\"employee_id\":96,\"employee_name\":\"Audra Bins\"},{\"employee_id\":97,\"employee_name\":\"Melba Larson\"},{\"employee_id\":98,\"employee_name\":\"Asa Schaefer\"},{\"employee_id\":99,\"employee_name\":\"Spencer Jenkins II\"},{\"employee_id\":100,\"employee_name\":\"Elda Brakus\"}]}"    string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change your JsonConvert to :
`var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);`

Alternatively you could remove the `employees` section from your JSON

Comment: That's great. If this solved your problem, then please mark this answer as 'accepted'. This will help other readers with similar problems to find a solution.